# SQL запрос на удаление полных дубликатов

Tags: sql

Есть таблица. В ней есть строки которые полностью дублируются.
Мне нужно удалить все дубли. Как для этого составить запрос?

| product_id | key | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | ключ_2 | значение_2 |
| 2 | ключ_2 | значение_2 |
| 3 | ключ_3 | значение_3 |
| 2 | ключ_2 | значение_2 |
| 4 | ключ_4 | значение_4 |
| 4 | ключ_4 | значение_4 |

Так делаю запрос чтобы выбрать дубликаты строк:

```
SELECT `product_id`, `key`, count(*)
FROM `eva_ms2_product_options`
WHERE `key` = 'mat_kovrika'
GROUP BY `product_id`
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Вы базу данных не указали. SQL в принципе не предназначен для работы с полностью идентичными строками. И такие строки отличаются только внутренними адресами или по другим признакам, которые у каждой БД свои, поэтому надо точно знать какая БД используется что бы сказать как это сделать. P.S. говорят что в MySQL достаточно создать уникальный ключ на таблицу и она сама удалит дубликаты.

Answer (score 1):

Выбираете все записи уникальные записи.

```
SELECT *
FROM eva_ms2_product_options
GROUP BY product_id, key, value
```

Дальше удаляете все записи из таблицы и вставляете эти.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE 
  FROM eva_ms2_product_options
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM (SELECT *, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY product_id,key,value) AS rw
                             FROM eva_ms2_product_options)f1
               WHERE f1.rw > 1
                 AND eva_ms2_product_options.product_id=f1.product_id
                 AND eva_ms2_product_options.key=f1.key
                 AND eva_ms2_product_options.value=f1.value)
```

p.s. почему в условии не через IN? - может удалить вообще все записи если ничего не найдёт

p.s.s. первый eva_ms2_product_options можно как-то обозвать, чтобы не запутаться, но на SQLLite не дал мне это сделать, от субд видимо зависит.